# How to increase variable every Sunday in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I need to increase value of some counter every Sunday.

I know, that I can get if today is Sunday, by this code:

```
def count
 @counter = 27226
  if Time.now.sunday?
    @counter +=315
  end
end
```

but it will be increased ONLY on Sunday and on other day it will be the same, not increased.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Don't use an instance variable. Write value in db or file. Additionnaly, should be in a cron

Comment: @apneadiving, I'm running app on Windows, so I can't use cron I guess. Maybe I will be reading value from json file, and if Sunday - increase it and overwrite it ?

Comment: Just be aware that if no one triggers the proper action on sunday, there'll be no update. Btw, in it's current state there's no real incrementation since you always start from the same value

Comment: I know, that I'm mistaken. That's why I'm asking here. Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does not have cron, but it does have an equivalent task scheduler.

See [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the scheduler and [this specific example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_spec_day) for configuring a "Wednesday-only" task.

A counter like you are describing does seem like the kind of value that you would normally store in a database, e.g. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is lightweight/convenient. You could take a look at [this nice intro on SQLite in Windows](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/installing-and-using-sqlite-with-ruby-on-windows/).

**Update**

In answer to your question in the comments...

> so I can run .rb file or ruby task with this ?

Yes, you can.  Here is a small recipe:

1) Install Ruby with this installer: http://rubyinstaller.org/
Note: Make sure to check the checkboxes that set it up to be able to run standalone Ruby scripts as-is.

2) Write a sample ruby script to periodically run. E.g., here's one that will throw a Windows dialog:

```
require 'Win32API'
title = "Test"
text = "Testing..."
dialog = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBox', 'LPPL', 'I')
result = dialog.call(0, text, title, 1)
```

3) And here's an example of "cron" setup from cmd.exe:
    schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn "Test Script" /tr c:\Users\manzoid\dev\test.rb

Comment: thanks, manzoid, so I can run `.rb` file or ruby task with this ?